# How do you make a column value slide to the right or the left using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This was an interview question.

If I have a table like this:

```
ID        FirstName       LastName
--        ---------       --------
1         Aaron           Aames
2         Malcolm         Middle
3         Zamon           Zorr
```

How can I get output that looks like this?

```
          Aaron           Aames
          Aames           Malcolm
          Malcolm         Middle
          Middle          Zamon
          Zamon           Zorr
```

Note: If you need a specific dialect to do it, use T-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way using a self-join.

```
CREATE TABLE temp (ID INT IDENTITY, FirstName VARCHAR(25), LastName VARCHAR(25));

INSERT INTO temp VALUES 
(N'Aaron', N'Aames'),
(N'Malcolm', N'Middle'),
(N'Zamon', N'Zorr');

WITH names(ID, Name, ColNum) AS(
    SELECT
        ID, FirstName, 1
    FROM temp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID, LastName, 2
    FROM temp
),
numbered AS(
    SELECT
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID, ColNum),
        Name
    FROM names
)
SELECT
    n.Name AS Name1, n2.Name AS Name2
FROM numbered n
INNER JOIN numbered n2
    ON n.rn = n2.rn - 1

DROP TABLE temp
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d91c4/2

Answer (score 1):

You have really high reputation, so this isn't just a "they asked me at an interview" kind of question.

There are several approaches.  I think the one that I would take is a `union all`.  Recognize that every other row is from the table.  The rest are from joining one row to the next.  So, that suggests:

```
select firstname, lastname
from likethis t
union all
select t.lastname, lead(t.firstname) over (order by id)
from likethis t
```

Alas, this gives you six rows instead of five, so that last one needs to be filtered out:

```
select firstname, lastname
from (select firstname, lastname
      from likethis t
      union all
      select t.lastname, lead(t.firstname) over (order by id)
      from likethis t
     ) t
where lastname is not null
order by firstname;
```

Note:  I cannot determine if the sort criteria is alphabetical or by id; these solutions assume it is alphabetical.

Second note:  I'm guessing this is not the solution they have in mind.  They probably are looking for a self-join.  But why bother when `lead()` does the work for you.

Comment: *'lead' is not a recognized built-in function name* --http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1ac3/1

Comment: It is starting in SQL Server 2012.  An interview question should not be about software that is two major versions out-of-date.

Comment: SqlFiddle is refusing to run SQL Server 2012 at the moment.

Comment: It has been refusing for a while, alas.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be solved this way:

```
SELECT
    t.LastName AS FirstName, t2.FirstName AS LastName
FROM    
    t
    INNER JOIN t as t2 ON t2.ID - 1 = t.ID
UNION
SELECT 
    t3.FirstName, t3.LastName 
FROM t AS t3
```

As far as I've checked correctly it should give the **final result set** the following way:

```
Aaron     Aames       <=  originates from t3:  where t3.ID = 1 
Aames     Malcolm     <=  originates from (t1, t2) Join:  where t2.ID = 2 and t.ID = 1
Malcolm   Middle      <=  originates from t3:  where t3.ID = 2
Middle    Zamon       <=  originates from (t1, t2) Join:  where t2.ID = 3 and t.ID = 2
Zamon     Zorr        <=  originates from t3:  where t3.ID = 3
```